# Harsh Critiques by Ibn Ezra

Tags: tanach, avraham-ibn-ezra

Can we attempt to compile a list of the sharp responses and lines by the Ibn Ezra throughout Tanach?  These are valuable (to me, anyways) for a couple of reasons:

1. Understanding what Ibn Ezra thought was important to demean, which leads us to a better understanding of his approach to Tanach in many cases (historical reasons, etc.).
2. They may/likely fall into the categories of permitted Leitzanus/Milsa Debedichusa, which can be utilized in Divrei Torah or other cases.

Comment: Why specifically Ibn Ezra?

Comment: @alex no particular reason, just someone who has a lot of content that can be used as answers...

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Other rishonim have harsh critiques as well. I don't think you can find anything that surpasses Ralbag saying of a Talmudic statement זהו שקר עצום ראוי שיברח ממנו כל בעל דעת/דת. But Ibn Ezra probably does have the most, and his insults/critiques often use cool wordplay.

Comment: @user6591 I edited it a bit.  Thoughts?

Comment: @Alex if you are referring to the meat eating idea, that was aggadda, to be fair.

Comment: @רבות Seems better suited

Comment: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/959/759 I think this is Too Broad

Comment: @DoubleAA on the other hand, msh210 says there that list questions are Ok.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות FWIW the Ramban was also known for such witty comments.

Comment: @donielf many Rishonim (and acharonim) were known for that, but not nearly as many instances (or as creative) as Ibn Ezra.

Comment: #1 may be "jews and not judaism". (CC @DoubleAA) #2 Leitzanus and Milsa Debedichusa are two different things, Leitzanus is only allowed to avodah zarah (see end of third chapter of Tractate Megilla), while Milsa Debedichusa is something the rabbis did before learning to (IIRC) put the students in a good mood so they can learn properly.

Comment: @Ploni #1 - that's why I wrote my two points above.  #2 I was aware of that, and that's why I wrote "permitted" (referring to leitzanusa daavodah zarah, which making fun of Kofrim may fall into) and "utilized for divrei torah", (which referred to the milsa debidichusa).

Comment: https://archive.org/details/zav-ibn-ezra-and-the-rabbinical-exegetical-tradition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a quick few examples from Sefer Bereishis:

Bereishis 23:6

> והאומרים כי השתחויתו היתה לשם **לא אמרו כלום** כי הכתוב אמר שהשתחוה
>   לבני חת

Bereishis 27:13

> ואחרים אמרו כי בנחת אמר אנכי ונשא קול במלת עשו בכורך **ואלה דברי רוח**
>   כי הנביאים יתחלקו לב' חלקים החלק הא' שליח במצות והחלק השני נביאי העתיד
>   ואם יצטרכו לאמר דבר שאיננו כהוגן לא יזיק רק השליח לא יתכן שיכזב כלל

Bereishis 27:40

> וישנים שלא הקיצו משנת האולת יחשבו כי אנחנו בגלות אדום ולא כן הדבר

Bereishis 30:17

> ובן אפרים אמר שהוא חסר אל"ף וטעמו ארוכות **והוא היה חסר אל"ף**

Bereishis 32:33

> ידוע כאשר העתיקו קדמונינו ז"ל ואין בו ספק **כי אם לחסרי הדעת ותולדות
>   שמפרשים שהוא האבר** ויפרשו הנשה מגזרת נשים

Bereishis 36:31

> ויצחקי אמר בספרו כי בימי יהושפט נכתבה זאת הפרשה ופירש הדורות כרצונו
>   **הכי קרא שמו יצחק כל השומע יצחק לו** כי אמר כי הדד הוא הדד האדומי ואמר כי
>   מהיטבאל אחות תחפנחס וחלילה חלילה שהדבר כמו שדבר על ימי יהושפט **וספרו
>   ראוי להשרף**

Bereshis 36:39

> והגאון אמר צורף זהב ואחרים אמרו רמז לעושים זהב מנחושת **ואלה דברי
>   רוח**

Bereishis 38:9

> ואתמה מבן תמים המזרחי שפי' ושחת ארצה שעשה לה שלא כדרך הנשים בעבור שלא
>   תהר והנה שחת הארץ שלה כי עליו היא יושבת בארץ **וזה פי' שגעון** וחלילה
>   חלילה להתגאל זרע הקדש בטנוף הטנוף

Bereishis 48:4

> וטעם הנני מפרך על דעת הגאון שאמר לי השם הנני מפרך ובן לא נולד לי רק
>   מתה רחל ועתה ידעתי כי בעבור בניך הנולדים לך אמר הנני מפרך **וזה הפי'
>   אין לו טעם וריח** כי מה הפרש בין בני יוסף ובין בני ראובן

Bereishis 49:6

> ואלה פירושים קרים בסודם אל תבא נפשי

Answer (score 5):

There's a nice one in Mishpatim 21:35:

> וכי יגף. אמר בן זוטא, כי רעהו - תואר לשור. ולא ראה, כי שור איש סמוך הוא, וכן הוא: שור רעהו. ואין לשור ריע רק בן זוטא לבדו. וזה השור שהוא תם ישלם בעליו חצי נזק:
>
> And if a bull pushes: Ben Zuta says that "its friend" describes the bull (and if a bull pushes its bull friend).  And he didn't realize that "a man's bull" is possessive, and similarly "his friend's bull".  Bulls don't have friends, except for Ben Zuta.

Comment: My personal favorite.

Comment: Who is Ben Zuta?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I've never heard of him outside of this Ibn Ezra, but http://www.encyclopedia.com/religion/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/ben-zuta-ben-zita-abu-al-surri http://www.orahsaddiqim.org/History/Hakhamim/Ben_Zuta_-_Ben_Zuta.shtml

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the ones that I remember (I'll add more as I find them) scattered through his writings, I'll try to add sources for each one later:

> ובן זוטא אמר, כל המספר דבר מעשה לא ישא פנים לנכבד להזכירו תחלה, וכתוב ותלד לעמרם את אהרן ואת משה ואת מרים אחותם (במד' כו, נט), והנה היא קטנה. **והנה זה המוכה בסנורים** שכח שם חם ויפת,
>
> ובן זוטא אמר, כי מלאתך על ההריון, ודמעך כנוי לשכבת זרע והיא הטפה, ואמר לא תאחר שלא יעכב מלקחת לו אשה, על כן אחריו: בכור בניך תתן לי, **וזה שגעון**.
>
> **ישתחקו עצמות חוי הכלבי**, שאמר, כי משה ידע את מיעוט הים ברדתו, ועת רבותו בעלותו בהמשכו, והוא העביר עמו במיעוט המים כמשפטו, ופרעה לא ידע מנהג הים על כן טבע. **ואלה דברי שגעון**, כי מנהג הים ברדתו לא ייבש מקום,
>
> **ירקב שם חוי**, שאמר, כי המן הוא הנקרא בלשון פרסי תרנגבי"ן, ובלשון ערבי מ"ן ובלשון לע"ז מנ"א, כי קושיות רבות עמדו עליו.
>
> **ישתחקו עצמות חוי הפושע**, שאמר כי בעבור שלא אכל לחם שבו פני משה יבשות כמו הקרן. וטעם וייראו (שמות לד ל), מפני שהיו פניו מכוערות. **ואיך לא פקח זה המקולל את עיניו,** כי לא יירא האדם לגשת אל האדם רק בעבור דבר פלא שנתחדש בו שלא ראה כמוהו.
>
> והארכתי כל כך בעבור **שאמר המשוגע שהפך בספרו דברי אלהים חיים**, אמר כי רצה משה לומר הגבל את העם, ויצא מפיו ההר במקום העם.
>
> **ישתחקו עצמות החוי הכלבי** שאמר לולי שענה אדם לא היה נמצא

A fantastic story (Rus 2:17)

> ויהי כאיפה שעורים - פעם אחת שאלני אדם מה טעם באיפה שעורים אמרתי לו **אין טעם לשאלה הזאת** כי הכתוב ספר מה היה אז נקלותי בעיניו ויאמר לי כי יש לו טעם **ואני החרשתי ממנו ולא שאלתיו**, והנה בא ביום אחד ואמר לי כי יש לו טעמים הרבה האחד שראתה רות בדרך נבואה כי עתיד היה אחד מבניה להעמיד עמוד על שם בעל' וטעם איפה צ"ו רמונים שהיו על העמוד וזה בגימטריא איפה, ופירוש שעורי' כמו שיעורים כמו שער בנפשו, וטעם אחר ויהי שתי מלות ארמית ועברית והיא כאשר ראתה שיתל' אבשלום שהוא מבניה והנה כ"ף עם אל"ף רמז לשנות אבשלום במותו ואחר כך איפה שערים לשון רבים בעבור היותו כבד עליו, וטעם אחר כי תחלת אות כאיפ' עם תחלת שעורים הוא בגמטריא ישי שהוא צדיק גמור **אז שמח וישב לבו בקרבו**: